# uiOutput with no container

Tags: r, shiny

I'm looking for a way to avoid a container when using uiOutput.

```
uiOutput(id, container = NULL)
```

does not seem to work.

Some background (if interested):
In my app I have several uiOutput(...) and I align them using flex. The problem I am facing now is that even when uiOutput is NULL an empty container is created which uses space because of it's "flex: 1 1 auto" css proberty. When no container is created, I could set this style dynamically within my server component.

Comment: reproducible example would be helpful. If I take uiOutput and does not return sthg from it doesnt take space. Does this behaviour come due to flex only?